# Scraping results differ when in a loop Python/BS4/Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a csv file that contains links I need to scrape. I also have it setup to use the same chrome browser for login purposes (the elements I need are only available when logged in). When I scrape a single page outside of the loop, I get the results I need from the page. When I put the same code into a loop to scrape all the links I get different results. I think it has to do with "source =" and or "soup ="

CSV file contains 3 links:

```
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/875-E-Arrowhead-Ln-84107/unit-44/home/77418264
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/35-W-American-Ave-84107/home/86446505
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987
```

Single page code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#####################################
chrome_driver = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
Chrome_options = Options()
Chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9015")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=Chrome_options)
#####################################
driver.get("https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987")
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
#####################################
address = soup.find('span', class_='street-address').text
print("      Address: " + address)
city = soup.find('span', class_='locality').text
print("         City: " + city)
state = soup.find('span', class_='region').text
print("        State: " + state)
zipcode = soup.find('span', class_='postal-code').text
print("      ZipCode: " + zipcode)
soldPrice = soup.find('div', class_='price-col number').text
print("   Sold Price: " + soldPrice)
ln = soup.find('div', class_='listing-agent-item')
Lname = ln.find_all('span')[1].text
print("Listing Agent: " + Lname)
bn = soup.find('div', class_='buyer-agent-item')
Bname = bn.find_all('span')[1].text
print(" Buying Agent: " + Bname)
date = soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"col-4"})
sDate = date.find_all('p')[0].text
print("         Date: " + sDate)
mls = soup.find('div', class_='sourceContent').text
print("   MLS Source: " + mls)
for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    if span.find(text='MLS#'):
            mlsNum = span.nextSibling.text
print("         MLS#: " + mlsNum)
driver.quit()
```

Single Page Results display perfectly:

```
      Address: 4551 S 200 E 
         City: Murray, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: $262,000 
Listing Agent: Jerold Ivie
 Buying Agent: Zac Eldridge
         Date: Dec 20, 2019
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1635000
[Finished in 3.3s]
```

Code for Loop with 'source=' and 'driver=' before loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
#####################################
chrome_driver = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
Chrome_options = Options()
Chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9015")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=Chrome_options)
#####################################
#driver.get("https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987")
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
#####################################
with open('UTlinks.csv') as file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file)
    for row in readCSV:
        url = str(row).replace("['","").replace("']","")
        print("_________________________________")
        print("Scraping: " + url)        
        driver.get(url)
        #source = driver.page_source
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
####################################
        try:
                address = soup.find('span', class_='street-address').text
                print("      Address: " + address)
        except:
                print("      Address: " + "NA")
        try:
                city = soup.find('span', class_='locality').text
                print("         City: " + city)
        except:
                print("         City: " + "NA")
        try:
                state = soup.find('span', class_='region').text
                print("        State: " + state)
        except:
                print("        State: " + "NA")
        try:
                zipcode = soup.find('span', class_='postal-code').text
                print("      ZipCode: " + zipcode)
        except:
                print("      ZipCode: " + "NA")
        try:
                soldPrice = soup.find('div', class_='price-col number').text
                print("   Sold Price: " + soldPrice)
        except:
                print("   Sold Price: " "NA")            
        try:
                ln = soup.find('div', class_='listing-agent-item')
                Lname = ln.find_all('span')[1].text
                print("Listing Agent: " + Lname)
        except:
                print("Listing Agent: " + "NA")
        try:
                bn = soup.find('div', class_='buyer-agent-item')
                Bname = bn.find_all('span')[1].text
                print(" Buying Agent: " + Bname)
        except:
                print(" Buying Agent: " + "NA")
        try:
                date = soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"col-4"})
                sDate = date.find_all('p')[0].text
                print("         Date: " + sDate)
        except:
                print("         Date: " + "NA")
        try:
                mls = soup.find('div', class_='sourceContent').text
                print("   MLS Source: " + mls)
        except:
                print("   MLS Source: " + "NA")
        try:
                for span in soup.find_all('span'):
                        if span.find(text='MLS#'):
                                mlsNum = span.nextSibling.text
                print("         MLS#: " + mlsNum)
        except:
                print("         MLS#: " + "NA")
```

Results with Loop:
You can see it prints the url's from the file then scrapes the currently open browser results 3 times... but grabs all the info needed for the open url.

```
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/875-E-Arrowhead-Ln-84107/unit-44/home/77418264
      Address: 4551 S 200 E 
         City: Murray, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: $262,000 
Listing Agent: Jerold Ivie
 Buying Agent: Zac Eldridge
         Date: Dec 20, 2019
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1635000
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/35-W-American-Ave-84107/home/86446505
      Address: 4551 S 200 E 
         City: Murray, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: $262,000 
Listing Agent: Jerold Ivie
 Buying Agent: Zac Eldridge
         Date: Dec 20, 2019
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1635000
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987
      Address: 4551 S 200 E 
         City: Murray, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: $262,000 
Listing Agent: Jerold Ivie
 Buying Agent: Zac Eldridge
         Date: Dec 20, 2019
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1635000
[Finished in 6.9s]
```

If I put the 'source=' and 'soup =' in the loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#####################################
chrome_driver = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
Chrome_options = Options()
Chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9015")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=Chrome_options)
#####################################
#driver.get("https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E- 84107/home/86457987")
#source = driver.page_source
#soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
#####################################
with open('UTlinks.csv') as file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file)
    for row in readCSV:
        url = str(row).replace("['","").replace("']","")
        print("_________________________________")
        print("Scraping: " + url)        
        driver.get(url)
        source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
####################################
        try:
                address = soup.find('span', class_='street-address').text
                print("      Address: " + address)
        except:
                print("      Address: " + "NA")
        try:
                city = soup.find('span', class_='locality').text
                print("         City: " + city)
        except:
                print("         City: " + "NA")
        try:
                state = soup.find('span', class_='region').text
                print("        State: " + state)
        except:
                print("        State: " + "NA")
        try:
                zipcode = soup.find('span', class_='postal-code').text
                print("      ZipCode: " + zipcode)
        except:
                print("      ZipCode: " + "NA")
        try:
                soldPrice = soup.find('div', class_='price-col number').text
                print("   Sold Price: " + soldPrice)
        except:
                print("   Sold Price: " "NA")            
        try:
                ln = soup.find('div', class_='listing-agent-item')
                Lname = ln.find_all('span')[1].text
                print("Listing Agent: " + Lname)
        except:
                print("Listing Agent: " + "NA")
        try:
                bn = soup.find('div', class_='buyer-agent-item')
                Bname = bn.find_all('span')[1].text
                print(" Buying Agent: " + Bname)
        except:
                print(" Buying Agent: " + "NA")
        try:
                date = soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"col-4"})
                sDate = date.find_all('p')[0].text
                print("         Date: " + sDate)
        except:
                print("         Date: " + "NA")
        try:
                mls = soup.find('div', class_='sourceContent').text
                print("   MLS Source: " + mls)
        except:
                print("   MLS Source: " + "NA")
        try:
                for span in soup.find_all('span'):
                        if span.find(text='MLS#'):
                                mlsNum = span.nextSibling.text
                print("         MLS#: " + mlsNum)
        except:
                print("         MLS#: " + "NA")
```

'source =' & 'soup =' in loop results:

---

```
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/875-E-Arrowhead-Ln-84107/unit-44/home/77418264
      Address: 875 E Arrow Head Ln S #44 
         City: Salt Lake City, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: NA
Listing Agent: Joe Olschewski
 Buying Agent: James Corey
         Date: NA
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1654937
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/35-W-American-Ave- 84107/home/86446505
      Address: 35 American Ave 
         City: Murray, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: NA
Listing Agent: Dana Conway
 Buying Agent: Rich Varga
         Date: NA
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1660023
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987
      Address: 4551 S 200 E 
         City: Murray, 
        State: UT
      ZipCode: 84107
   Sold Price: NA
Listing Agent: Jerold Ivie
 Buying Agent: Zac Eldridge
         Date: NA
   MLS Source: WFRMLS
         MLS#: 1635000
[Finished in 8.6s]
```

Now it's working fine but not grabbing 'Sold Price:' or 'Sold Date:'. If I take the error handling off, it throws this error:

```
soldPrice = soup.find('div', class_='price-col number').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When viewing the first link, I am finding that this element does not contain a number. soup.find('div', class_='price-col number')

Comment: @Sri, not sure what you mean? It works fine outside the loop with the same selector.

Comment: I just ran it and it doesn't work at this line. soldPrice = soup.find('div', class_='price-col number').text. I get NoneType object has no attribute text, which means it could not find that element.

Comment: @Sri, the data after ZipCode is only available if logged in. You can see from the first block of code and results, it is there and finds it. Even the second block of code. Can't figure out why only these two elements give me grief when in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API to get the data. Tad tricky though. I'm able to pull the data without registering/logging in (although the only thing I couldn't find in the html or json responses was the buying agents for some reason). But if you login, it appears to then give that data. Looks like everything else (and MORE) is there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

links = ['https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/875-E-Arrowhead-Ln-84107/unit-44/home/77418264',
'https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/35-W-American-Ave-84107/home/86446505',
'https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987']

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'email':'username@email.com',
'pwd':'thisIsThePassword'}

#cookiesStr = ''
with requests.Session() as s:       
    login = s.post('https://www.redfin.com/stingray/do/api-login', headers=headers, params=payload)
    #cookies = s.cookies.get_dict()
    #for k, v in cookies.items():
    #    cookiesStr += '%s=%s;' %(k,v)

#headers.update({'cookie':cookiesStr}) 

for url in links:
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    for script in scripts:
        if '_tLAB.wait(function()' in script.text and '/stingray/api/home/details/belowTheFold' in script.text:
            jsonStr = script.text
            jsonStr = '{' + jsonStr.split('{',2)[-1].rsplit(')',2)[0]

            jsonData2 = json.loads(jsonStr)
            jsonData2 = json.loads(jsonData2['res']['text'].split('&&')[-1])

            address = jsonData2['payload']['amenitiesInfo']['addressInfo']['street']
            city = jsonData2['payload']['amenitiesInfo']['addressInfo']['city']
            state = jsonData2['payload']['amenitiesInfo']['addressInfo']['state']
            zipcode = jsonData2['payload']['amenitiesInfo']['addressInfo']['zip']

            mlsSource = jsonData2['payload']['amenitiesInfo']['provider']
            listingAgent = jsonData2['payload']['amenitiesInfo']['mlsDisclaimerInfo']['listingAgentName']

        if 'InitialContext = ' in script.text:
            jsonStr = script.text.split('InitialContext = ')[-1].split('root.__reactServerState.Config')[0].rsplit(';',1)[0]
            jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

            dataAPIs = jsonData['ReactServerAgent.cache']['dataCache']
            jsonData2 = json.loads(dataAPIs['/stingray/api/home/details/aboveTheFold']['res']['text'].split('&&')[-1])
            soldPrice = jsonData2['payload']['addressSectionInfo']['priceInfo']['amount']
            soldDate = jsonData2['payload']['mediaBrowserInfo']['sashes'][0]['lastSaleDate']

            jsonData2 = json.loads(dataAPIs['/stingray/api/home/details/initialInfo']['res']['text'].split('&&')[-1])
            mls = jsonData2['payload']['mlsId']

            jsonData2 = json.loads(dataAPIs['/stingray/api/home/details/mainHouseInfoPanelInfo']['res']['text'].split('&&')[-1])
            buyingAgents = jsonData2['payload']['mainHouseInfo']['buyingAgents'][0]['agentInfo']['agentName']

    print("_________________________________")
    print("Scraping: " + url)  
    print('%15s: %s' %('Address',address))
    print('%15s: %s' %('City',city))
    print('%15s: %s' %('State',state))
    print('%15s: %s' %('Zipcode',zipcode))
    print('%15s: $' %('Sold Price') + f'{soldPrice:,}')
    print('%15s: %s' %('Listing Agent',listingAgent))
    print('%15s: %s' %('Buying Agent',buyingAgents))
    print('%15s: %s' %('Date',soldDate))
    print('%15s: %s' %('MLS Source',mlsSource))
    print('%15s: %s' %('MLS#',mls))
```

**Output:**

```
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/875-E-Arrowhead-Ln-84107/unit-44/home/77418264
        Address: 875 E Arrow Head Lane South Unit 44
           City: Salt Lake City
          State: UT
        Zipcode: 84107
     Sold Price: $179,900
  Listing Agent: Joe Olschewski
   Buying Agent: James Corey
           Date: MAR 12, 2020
     MLS Source: WFRMLS
           MLS#: 1654937
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/35-W-American-Ave-84107/home/86446505
        Address: 35 American Ave
           City: Murray
          State: UT
        Zipcode: 84107
     Sold Price: $317,500
  Listing Agent: Dana Conway
   Buying Agent: Rich Varga
           Date: MAR 25, 2020
     MLS Source: WFRMLS
           MLS#: 1660023
_________________________________
Scraping: https://www.redfin.com/UT/Murray/4551-S-200-E-84107/home/86457987
        Address: 4551 South 200 E
           City: Murray
          State: UT
        Zipcode: 84107
     Sold Price: $262,000
  Listing Agent: Jerold Ivie
   Buying Agent: Zac Eldridge
           Date: DEC 20, 2019
     MLS Source: WFRMLS
           MLS#: 1635000
```

Comment: Yeah, @chitown88. I really need that buyer info though. I tried the API. Instead of time delay, I tried making a loop until elements where found to run the script... it always throws the same error like it cant find the element text. baffled

Comment: @RyanEvans. I’ll give it look again tomorrow. I’ll create a login and go at it that way.

Comment: @RyanEvans Ok. Yup you do need to login to get that. I adjusted the code. You just need to put in your username, pass.

Comment: Been playing around with it. It doesn't throw any errors but won't print any results. Tried to send results to a csv but gives me a blank file. Trying to decipher your code but it's way more advanced than my attempt.. any ideas?